# DataGridView "loses" column with List<object>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a List ComparedItem which I want to display in datagridview dataGridViewCompare.
Some properties of ComparedItem are Lists too, and dataGridViewCompare will not display these columns.

Actually I don't want to display the list in a cell, but I want to show the content of this cell in a textbox when the user select a specific row.

```
public class ComparedItem
{
    public ElementItem SourceElement { get; private set; }
    public ElementItem TargetElement { get; private set; }
    public bool HasErrors { get; set; }
    public List<ErrorType> ErrorTypes { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyErrorNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> DetailsInconsistencyError { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSpecialCharsError { get; set; }
    public string DetailsTextError { get; set; }

    public ComparedItem(ElementItem source, ElementItem target)
    {
        SourceElement = source;
        TargetElement = target;
        DetailsInconsistencyError = new List<string>();
        DetailsInconsistencyError.Add("Test"); // <- Temp
        ErrorTypes = new List<ErrorType>();
        FriendlyErrorNames = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

In my main form:

```
List<ComparedItem> = new List<ComparedItem> comparedItems;
// fill list in some other code...
dataGridViewCompare.DataSource = comparedItems;
```

dataGridViewCompare shows all the lines I expect, but only the columns

- SourceElement
- TargetElement
- HasErrors
- FriendlyErrorNames
- DetailsSpecialCharsError
- DetailsTextError

are displayed.

- ErrorTypes and
- DetailsInconsistencyError

are lost.

Is it not possible to hold Lists in datagridview cells?

Comment: I don't think so. It is in the DataSource however, so you can pull out the values and display them in the TextBox as you want to. What sort of display would you have expected in the cell? - You could add dummy members in your class that will show a string representation of the two lists: `public string list_display { get { return list.Count + " Elements"; } }`

Comment: My plan was to hide the two columns in the datagridview and just to pull out the data for formatting and displaying in the textbox. OK, so I use the datasource instead and hope, that the index of grid and datasource will stay in sync... :-) Too bad I cannot accept this comment as answer.

Comment: I have added an answer that should clear up both issues: how to access the data and make sure it is the right item..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can display a `List<T>` in a DGV cell.

It is in the `DataSource` however, so you can pull out the values and display them in the `TextBoxes` as you want to.

Here is how to access the item in your list the (first selected) row is bound to:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) return;
    ComparedItem ci = (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as ComparedItem);

    if (ci != null) 
    {
      textBox1.Text = someStringRepresentation(ci.ErrorTypes);
      textBox2.Text = someStringRepresentation(ci.DetailsInconsistencyError);
    }
}
```

Depending on the `SelectionMode` you may want to add similar code to the `CurrentCellChanged` event etc..